# How can I Close a Boot Strap Modal Using C#

Tags: c#, bootstrap-modal

I am using a Modal for the first time and need some help I have this Modal

```
<div id="User_Modal" class ="container">
    <div class ="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="modal" id="viewUserModal" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Enter You Pin To Continue</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div>
                                <label for="inputPinNumber">Pin Number</label>
                                <br />
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Pin #" type="number" id="txtUserPin" runat="server"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnUser" Text="Go" OnClick="btnUser_Click" />
                            <button class =" btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I open or call the Modal using this C# code on the btnUser_Click method with this C# code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal", "$('#viewUserModal').modal('show');", true);
```

After the user enters the Pin number I want to get that value check it against my data and then close the Modal.  I trying to do that with this code:

```
protected void btnUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strUserPin = txtUserPin.Value.ToString();
        if (strUserPin.Length > 0)
        {
            Session["SessionPinEntered"] = strUserPin;
            string strUser = Email.GetUser(strUserPin);
            bool bolIsManager = true;//CheckUser(strUser);
            if (bolIsManager)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Close Modal", "$('#viewUserModal').modal('close');", true);
                pnlGrid.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

The code runs but the Modal does not close and my hidden asp Panel is not shown.
Can someone explain why this is not working?

UPDATE:
I was able to figure out how to hide the Modal with this code change:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Hide Modal", "$('#viewUserModal').modal('hide');", true);
```

But the C# code to make the asp Panel visible is still not working.  In debug I can watch the code being called and steps over put does not run?  What's going on with that and how can I get this fixed

Comment: Add lead and tail spaces `" $('#viewUserModal').modal('hide'); "` on each scripted tag, this will insure that your js won't be stacked together, which would not run as expected. As I have used it the same method you're approaching, and when I checked on the page source to check wither the script is executed or not, I found that all js code were stacked together into one script tag.

Comment: let me know if this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks iSR5 I made those changes.  The js code ran and I can hide the Modal.  Still having the issue where the C# code to make the ASP Panel visible is still not working.  Any idea why that would be happening

Comment: For the panel, it's not clear why it's not working, you need to post its related code to be reviewed. but if it's a nested panel or the visibility of parent container is changed to false, then you must set the parent's visibility to true as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to rebind the grid after I changed the panel from being hidden.  Once I did that the radgrid shows the data